# java Printing inorder BST with parenthesis

Tags: java, string, binary-search-tree, parentheses, inorder

I want to return a String containing all keys in the tree, in the order they are stored. The keys in each subtree should be contained in a parenthesis.

```
        _7_
      /     \
   _3_      8
 /     \
1       6
 \     /
  2   4
       \
        5
```

The output for this BST should be `(((()1(()2()))3((()4(()5()))6()))7(()8()))`.
My code for doing this is:

```
public String printKeysInOrder() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return "()";
    }

    printInOrderRec(root);

    System.out.print(sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

private String printInOrderRec(Node root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    sb.append("(");
    printInOrderRec(root.left);
    sb.append("(");
    sb.append(")");

    sb.append(root.val);

    printInOrderRec(root.right);

    return null;
}
```

Which gives me the output: `(((()1(()2()3((()4(()5()6()7(()8`.
I have been working on this for ages and can't figure out where and how to append the missing brackets. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before jumping into coding solution, let's try to draw how the *output should be* can be generated.

```
(--------------------------------7-------)
 (------------3-----------------) (--8--)
  (--1-------) (------------6--)   () ()
   () (--2--)   (--4-------) ()
       () ()     () (--5--)
                     () ()
```

Here every enclosed pair of parentheses defines a [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). I am not trying to describe each call stack, otherwise this answer would be arbitarily long. However, from the drawing we can find out 5 portions at each call stack.

1. Left paranthesis
2. Left child
3. Value
4. Right child
5. Right paranthesis

So, the your `printInOrderRec` method may look like:

```
private void printInOrderRec(Node root) {
    sb.append("(");
    if (root != null) {
        printInOrderRec(root.left);
        sb.append(root.val);
        printInOrderRec(root.right);
    }
    sb.append(")");
}
```

**Note:** I have made the return type `void` because in your code it returns nothing but null.

Comment: Thank you sazzad for your clear explanation! I appreciate that